No FileSystem for scheme"s3" trino s3 with hive meta store
Getting an exception while trying to create a table using the s3 location from trino cli.

org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException No FileSystem for scheme "s3"

what is the changes required to get this set up working?
copied hadoop-aws-2-10.1.jar and aws-java-sdk-1.11.890 also to hive lib and trino lib also updated  core site.xml in trio conf with fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey,awsAccessKeyID and s.impl but no luck

Do you have any fs.s3.impl configuration? And did you try s3a instead? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Introducing_the_Hadoop_S3A_client.

yes , this makes error bit better , but it gives now java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out some files are created at s3 bucket like snap-877121715290998144-1-6d9f2c29-ee58-421f-be59-9b20b9fadbd6.avro and 00000-2069f366-0109-48e4-9f7d-3380cf606f9c.metadata.json but still unable to create table..

yes , this makes error bit better , but it gives now java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out some files are created at s3 bucket like snap-877121715290998144-1-6d9f2c29-ee58-421f-be59-9b20b9fadbd6.avro and 00000-2069f366-0109-48e4-9f7d-3380cf606f9c.metadata.json but still unable to create table.. hive meta server log: ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.MetaStoreUtils: [TThreadPoolServer WorkerProcess-48]: Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException getFileStatus on s3a://xx-xxxx-ent-122333466777788/test: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTT

updated end point in hive config as well now it's just timeout FAILED (HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR)  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.createTable(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:874)
at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.BridgingHiveMetastore.createTable(BridgingHiveMetastore.java:218)
at io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.tracing.TracingHiveMetastore.lambda$createTable$12(TracingHiveMetastore.java:215)

Please [edit] your question to include the changes you've made and include the formatted error logs. If you're getting a Hive timeout, then S3 is no longer the issue and you'll need to use networking tools to debug the connection

This has resolved table can be created as well after updating fs.s3a.xxx parameters ... the question now is on how to refer a parquet file from s3 location to create trino table ..

Feel free to answer below what specific settings you've changed. Tables are generally created over entire directories, not specific files
